# IIS and MVC5 Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I have two separate databases(my own db and identity tables).
My web config strings looks like:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection"  connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnet-MVC-20160209053715.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="CVJobOnlineEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=STEFAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=CVJobOnline;User Id=DB_9F4064_CVJobOnline_admin;Password=pass123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I can access to my web through IIS for landing page and etc. But when I want to do login, it cannot find default conn - identity tables obviously.

I have this error:

> Cannot create file 'D:\AdeccoCVPMIv2\App_Data\aspnet-MVC-20160209053715.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>   Thanks.

Comment: Not being cheeky, but did you read the error message "Cannot create file 'D:\AdeccoCVPMIv2\App_Data\aspnet-MVC-20160209053715.mdf' **because it already exists."** . The error is telling you that the database file "aspnet-MVC-20160209053715.mdf" can't be created because it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of ASP.NET template, the connection will work only if you have either both the database and .mdf file, or none of them. What you can do as of now is one of the following
1. Delete the database if exists and delete the .mdf file from app_Data folder in the projects directory.
2. Change the name of both .mdf file and database in the connection string.
Hope that it helps you.